# Import javascript Module in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to implement a Map API in an Angular 13 project but I have just a Javascript file. Apparently it's based on TypeScript then easily importable but I don't know how...

The file starts by this code :

```
!function() {
function e(t, n, i) {
    function r(a, s) {
        if (!n[a]) {
            if (!t[a]) {
                var l = "function" == typeof require && require;
                if (!s && l)
                    return l(a, !0);
                if (o)
                    return o(a, !0);
                var u = new Error("Cannot find module '" + a + "'");
                throw u.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
                u
            }
            var h = n[a] = {
                exports: {}
            };
            t[a][0].call(h.exports, function(e) {
                var n = t[a][1][e];
                return r(n || e)
            }, h, h.exports, e, t, n, i)
        }
        return n[a].exports
    }
    for (var o = "function" == typeof require && require, a = 0; a < i.length; a++)
        r(i[a]);
    return r
}
return e
```

}()({

In the documentation, I need just do this :

```
var map = new f4.map.Map('#map');
```

But f4 is undefined...

How i can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You have been passed a minified file, you can tell for the syntax and for the variables names. You need to import a typescript definitions file (*.d.ts), not a minified javascript file.

Comment: The problem is that I have only this file (in reality just an URL of JS file). How i can create this ts file and how I import it ?